# Merging multiple RTP using asterisk for conferences

Tags: asterisk, rtp

I would like to join a multicast RTP stream into an asterisk conference (confbridge). Any tips on how to is welcome.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Asterisk not support multicast rtp at current moment. You can try use kamailio if you proficient enought, but that is expert-class task.

Comment: @arheops user1---joins--->(asterisk1 conference)---Page(multicastrtp)--->multicast group------->(asterisk2 conference room 2000 + asterisk3 conference room 3000 +asterisk4 conference 4000)

the above is my scenario, in simple word i need to send multicast rtp from one conference (asterisk) to n-1 asterisk conference rooms.

Please let me know how we can approach this with the help of kamailio and asterisk

Comment: It will send 3 different rtp sessions. Yes, you can do it using originate command or call files. No, you can't do it if you want users in other rooms speak.

Comment: @arheops how would you suggest we receive RTP on Kamailio and send it as SIP invite/call to asterisk?

Comment: For rtp you have use rtpproxy.

Comment: @arheops is there perhaps a certain documentation or anything of that sort I could refer to, to do this ?

Comment: There are near zero documentation, since it is not common use case and rtpproxy is opensource project(not much people want write doc for free). Sorry, as i say this one project require expert level. There are no simple way read one article and did it.

Comment: You are just wrong way very likly. If you need connect multiple rooms on different asterisks, you not need multicast. IF you need just give ability listen to many people(no speak), you need use streamiing solutions like icestream.

Answer (score 0):

We use the application konference or vonference (add video support) both GPL.
You can add a user as speaker and connect a lot of listeaners for example.
You can control the conference an play audio at anytime.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/appconference/

or

https://github.com/voximal/asterisk-vonference

Comment: On confbridge thats also posible. But you answer some other question, not what TS asks.